# How to capture new column (current_date) from select statement inside resultMap -- mybatis, java

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

In the table `plugin` there is a column `id` for which I am able to capture records but when it comes to a new column which is not part of table how can I capture the records for it. For example, if I need to return `current_date` then how this can be achieved **as this is not a column name** in `plugin` table.

mapper.xml

```
<resultMap type="my.class.plugins.Plugin" id="pluginMap">
    <constructor>
        <idArg column="id" javaType = "java.util.UUID"/>
    </constructor>

</resultMap>
```

```
<select id="getPluginById" resultMap="pluginMap">
 SELECT id, current_date
 FROM public.plugin
</select>
```

java class

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonSerialize
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutablePlugin.class)
@Value.Style(allParameters = true)
public abstract class Plugin {

    public Plugin() {

    }

    /**
     * returns id from table plugin
     * @return
     */
    public abstract UUID getId();
}
```

Comment: Please add the class definition of `my.class.plugins.Plugin` and indicate the field to which you are trying to map `current_date`.

Comment: @ave I have added the java class. The class is abstract. I want to fetch today_date / current_date from sql select command. The problem I facing is I cannot map the date portion as curent_date is not a column in table

Comment: A few basics: 1) MyBatis cannot instantiate abstract class (Java does not allow it). There must be a concrete class that has fields for `today_date` and `current_date`.  2) Unlike ORMs, MyBatis maps columns in the result set. It does not matter if the columns are defined in a table or not.